# AngularJS Multistep Form Single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a multi step form using AngularJS. I am not getting how to get the previous step. Flow of my form is two way. One can go from step 1 to step 4 via **A way** *step1-->step2-->step3-->step4* and **B way** is step1-->step3-->step4.
I used `<button  class="SubmitPrev" ng-click="step = 1">Prev</button>` code for getting the previous step. But when user is going by **A way** then previous step of step3 should be step2 and via **B way** the previous step of step3 should be step1. In step3, i can not use my previous button code because previous step of step3 depends on which way user is coming. I also tried to create alias of step3 but its increasing the number of lines as my form is consists of many steps with many ways. Is there any other way to call the previous step?

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
 
  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {         

       $scope.name = '';    
        $scope.data = {
      singleSelect: null,
       multipleSelect: [],
       option1: 'option-1',
     };
     $scope.forceUnknownOption = function() {
       $scope.data.singleSelect = 'nonsense';
     };

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<form name='myform' id="myform" ng-init="step = 1" ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)">

<div ng-show="step==1">
<h3>Which step</h3>
<div ng-form='step1form'>
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 2"><p>Step 2</p>
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3"><p>Step 3</p>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="step==2">
<h3 class="zoomIn">which step</h3>
<div ng-form='step2form'>
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3"><p>Step 3</p>
<button  class="SubmitPrev" ng-click="step = 1">Prev</button>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="step==3">
<h3 class="zoomIn">which step</h3>
<div ng-form='step3form'>
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="!step3form.$valid" ng-click="step = 4"><p>Step 4</p>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="step==4">
<h3 class="zoomIn">which step</h3>
<div ng-form='step4form'>
<p>Finish</p>
</div>
</div>

</form>

<script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use: [Angular Multi step form](https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form)

multiStepForm is an angular module to create multi step forms and wizards. Create your steps like your would create your views with ngRoute or ui-router!

some of the main features:

- Steps are controlled views and are easily configured
- Isolated or non isolated scopes for steps
- Track step validity if it contains a form

Answer (score 0):

Store the current and previous step in your controller. So when clicking the previous button, set the current step to the previous step.

If that doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll provide a Plunker.

Here's a quick Plunker to demonstrate:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ofha6qAyNgJZj7XQ5Zk7?p=preview

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ng-if="currentStep == 1">
      <h1>Step 1</h1>
      <button ng-click="setStep(2)">Go to step 2</button>
      <button ng-click="setStep(3)">Jump to step 3</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="currentStep == 2">
      <h1>Step 2</h1>
      <button ng-click="setStep(3)">Go to step 3</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="currentStep == 3">
      <h1>Step 3</h1>
    </div>

    <br>
    <button ng-if="previousStep > 0" ng-click="setStep(previousStep)">Go to your previous step ({{previousStep}})</button>
    <button ng-if="currentStep > 1" ng-click="setStep(currentStep - 1)">Go to {{currentStep - 1}}</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.currentStep = 1;
  $scope.previousStep = 0;

  $scope.setStep = function(step) {

    if (step == 1) { // If first step hide previous button
      $scope.previousStep = 0;
    } else {
       $scope.previousStep = $scope.currentStep;
    }

    $scope.currentStep = step;
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually i am new to angularJS. I don't have that much knowledge.How do i store the previous step in controller?

Comment: I've posted a quick Plunker to demonstrate

Comment: thanks for your help. Its showing the previous step but it still not going from step3-->step2-->step1..

Comment: It does just using a different button:

Open the Plunker > click go to step 2 > click jump to step 3 > click go to 2 > click go to 1.

Comment: i wanted it to work in just one button. Is there any other way to do this?